# SQL server - Update one column based on the values of other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say there are five columns in the table and I'd like to update the column E based on the value of column A,B,C,D. If the corresponding value is Y, then write the column name as part of the value in column E. The expected result is shown in the second image.

Originally, the data in the table looks like this

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you number of columns is fixed, then you can use a `CASE` statement.

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  A nvarchar(1),
  B nvarchar(1),
  C nvarchar(1),
  D nvarchar(1),
  E nvarchar(10)
);

insert into data (A, B, C, D) values
('Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'),
('N', 'N', 'N', 'Y'),
('N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N'),
('Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N');
```

**Solution**

```
update d
set d.E = substring(
          case d.A when 'Y' then ',A' else '' end
        + case d.B when 'Y' then ',B' else '' end
        + case d.C when 'Y' then ',C' else '' end
        + case d.D when 'Y' then ',D' else '' end,
         2, 100)
from data d;
```

**Result**

```
select * from data;

A   B   C   D   E
--- --- --- --- -------
Y   N   Y   Y   A,C,D
N   N   N   Y   D
N   Y   Y   N   B,C
Y   Y   Y   N   A,B,C
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a91af/11)

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server now supports `CONCAT_WS()`, which I would recommend:

```
update t
    set E = concat_ws(',',
                      case d.A when 'Y' then 'A' end,
                      case d.B when 'Y' then 'B' end,
                      case d.C when 'Y' then 'C' end,
                      case d.D when 'Y' then 'D' end
                     );
```

However, it seems silly to store this information when it can be calculated -- and *always* up-to-date:

```
alter table t add E as (concat_ws(',',
                                  case d.A when 'Y' then 'A' end,
                                  case d.B when 'Y' then 'B' end,
                                  case d.C when 'Y' then 'C' end,
                                  case d.D when 'Y' then 'D' end
                                 )
                        );
```

Computed columns are calculated when they are queried.  They are always up-to-date and never have to be updated.

Comment: It is needed for a quick datamod before drop A,B,C,D columns

Comment: @Ning . . . Dropping the original columns in favor of a comma-delimited string seems like multiple steps *backward*.  That is, it seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score -2):

```
update table_name set E='A,C,D' where A='Y' and B='N' and C='Y' and D='Y'
```

If you set id column for your table it is easy to update